# paramiko authentication Exception Error

Tags: python, paramiko

While I am running the Below Given Pyhton code, I am running into authentication issue though it was running fine until I install python argparse module, don't really know what was broken.

**`Python 2.6.6`**

```
 $python gopy4.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./.gopy4.py", line 20, in <module>
        client.connect(HOST, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 322, in connect
        self._auth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 476, in _auth
        raise saved_exception
    paramiko.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.
```

Below is the Scripts which was working few mins back , when i install argparse since then its throwing above error.

```
$ cat .gopy4.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
sys.stderr = open('/dev/null')       # Silence silly warnings from paramiko
import paramiko as pm
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
import os

class AllowAllKeys(pm.MissingHostKeyPolicy):
    def missing_host_key(self, client, hostname, key):
        return

HOST = '192.1.10.1'
USER = 'karn'
PASSWORD = 'mypass'

client = pm.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AllowAllKeys())
client.connect(HOST, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)

channel = client.invoke_shell()
stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('rb')

stdin.write('''
hostname
uname -a
uptime
who
exit
''')
print stdout.read()

stdout.close()
stdin.close()
client.close()
```

Install screen shot....

```
$ sudo rpm -ivh python-argparse-1.2.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm
[sudo] password for karn:
warning: python-argparse-1.2.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:python-argparse        ########################################### [100%]
```

Comment: I wonder if some other modules were involved when installing `argparse` module... (I mean, you might update or install them unintentionally). You could debug with `pdb` or other debugging tools to investigate the cause, or could you give us more detail log?

Comment: @tsuda7   .. i Just edited my Question with the install logs.. nothing else done as only single rpm base install was done.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of paramiko you're using, but `auth_handler.py` generates such an `AuthenticationException`... It seems nothing to do with installing `argparse` though... Can you uninstall `argparse` and see if your code works fine?

Comment: @tsuda7 .. i tried that already but it did not help.

Comment: There was backtick character in `HOST = '192.1.10.1'` which was the cause of this , now running fine.

Answer (score 0):

There was backtick character in `HOST = '192.1.10.1'` which was the cause of this , now running fine.